# Html email adds random tag when sending

Tags: html, email

I created a signature in outlook 2010. Then I opened the htm file. I added a a tag around the text with a href and added text decoration:none and a color. Now when I send my email it shows still with a underline. My styles are still in the mail but on the span tag IN the a tag. It just adds a random span tag and cut the styles from the a tag.

```
<a href="https://www.site.nl/" style="text-decoration:none; color:#333;">www.site.nl</a>
```

It shows up like this :

```
<a href="https://www.site.nl/">
<span style="text-decoration:none; color:#333;">www.site.nl</span>
</a>
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: This behaviour is probably created by the mail software you are using to look at the mail and not by the HTML itself.

Comment: I can't find someone with the same issue on google. Is it really?